# First query against realtime database return nothing

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

**The problem**

I have this weird behavior with realtime-database where no matter what i do - i can't get a response from the database as the first action...

**Firebase.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';


// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = { *** }

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const db = getDatabase(app);
```

**My apiCall**

```
    const wardrobeQuery = query(ref(db, dbName), limitToFirst(20));
    get(wardrobeQuery).then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((item) => {
```

**The question**

Is there a way to build the firebase.js file so that i can call initialize when the user performs a successful log-in so that the api is ready to load data when hitting the landing-page ???

**EDIT**

i tinkered with my code a bit and realised that other parts of my code would fire first try. If i do the following it works

```
const snap: DataSnapshot = (await get(ref(getDatabase(), dbName)));
```

**NEW QUESTION**

how do i limit the number of results and or order the results using the above snippet ?

Comment: There's not a lot for us here to go on. Please edit your question to show: 1) the value of `dbName` that you're reading from, or better yet - use a hard-coded value,  2) the part database that you're reading from (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).  --- 3) the result you get back from the database, typically a `console.log` is easiest.

Comment: querying works - just not on the first attempt...
is there a way to initialize the firebase api before running the first query ?

preferably - as stated in my post - is there a way to do this when the user has made a successful login ???

Comment: The `initializeApp` calls is synchronous, and it's unclear how the two snippets you posted are related (and how the login is involved between them). Can you **edit your question** to [show a single, minimal snippet of code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: if i do "const snap: DataSnapshot = (await get(ref(getDatabase(), dbName)))" it returns data first try

so it seems there's something wrong with my original use of query

Comment: i fixed it with an await before the get in the original query...

Answer (score 0):

jeeez!

this is the fix;

```
const wardrobeQuery = query(ref(db, dbName), limitToFirst(20));
AWAIT get(wardrobeQuery).then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((item) => {
```

an await - that's it!